# Page to route 404 with login

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My problem is when I started using a `router.beforeEach()` he won't go to the page of 404 when I typ a not existing link. He just go to page with the defaukt layout I use. I use `router.beforeEach()` for checking if a user is logged in or not. Is there something missing, or is there something wrong?

This is my `router.js`

```
let router = new Router({
mode: 'history',
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'login',
        component: () => import('./views/Login.vue'),
        meta: {
            layout: "empty"
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'home',
        component: () => import('./views/Home.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/404',
        name: '404',
        component: () => import('./views/404.vue'),
        meta: {
            layout: "empty"
        },
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/404'
    },
    {
        path: '/*',
        redirect: '/404'
    }
]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UH'));
    console.log(isLoggedIn);
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    if (isLoggedIn === null){
        if (requiresAuth && !isLoggedIn.user) {
            next('/');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, when a user type something wrong in the url and is **not logged in**, this user is redirected to '/' instead of 404.

It's because the beforeEach hook is used before your route redirect `{path: '*', redirect: '/404'}` and your condition to redirect an user not logged in if the page requiresAuth is true.

To solve the problem, add an other condition like this:

```
if (isLoggedIn === null){
    if (requiresAuth && !isLoggedIn.user) {
        if (!to.matched.length) {
           next('/404');
        } else {
           next('/');
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }

} else {
    next();
}
```